# shiny app works locally but not on shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny, server, local, shinyapps

I have browsed on SO and the R community, it looks like this error may result from vary reasons, so I still post my problem here, please give me some suggestions. Thank you very much.

Here is the code that works locally:

```
library(shiny)

ui=fluidPage(
  titlePanel('hello shiny'),
  sidebarPanel(
    textInput('ID',label='ID:'),actionButton('goButton',label='submit')
    ),
  mainPanel(imageOutput('out'))
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  fullnames=list.files(path = "/Users/u/myapp/www", pattern = ".png");
  reactive({
            input$ID=gsub(pattern = '\\.png','',fullnames)
            }
           );
  output$out=renderImage(
    {
     filenames=normalizePath(file.path('/Users/u/myapp/www',paste(input$ID,'.png',sep='')));
     list(src=filenames)
    },
    deleteFile = F
     
  )
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

however, there is a warning:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7453
Warning in normalizePath(file.path("/Users/u/myapp/www", paste(input$ID,  :
  path[1]="/Users/ya/myapp/www/.png": No such file or directory
```

I guess it is the input that caused this error, but the similar warning on the server log shows that there is an ID '20191704465.png' in the code (the ID I fill in in the textInput widget):

```
2021-08-12T13:32:22.863287+00:00 shinyapps[4485062]: Listening on http://127.0.0.1:38432
2021-08-12T13:32:26.831219+00:00 shinyapps[4485062]:   path[1]="/Users/u/myapp/www/.png": No such file or directory
2021-08-12T13:32:26.831217+00:00 shinyapps[4485062]: Warning in normalizePath(file.path("/Users/u/myapp/www", paste(input$ID,  :
2021-08-12T13:32:31.471638+00:00 shinyapps[4485062]:   path[1]="/Users/u/myapp/www/20191704465.png": No such file or directory
```

but somehow the server still shows:

```
path[1]="/Users/u/myapp/www/20191704465.png": No such file or directory
```

What went wrong with the code?

Comment: Replace `path = "/Users/u/myapp/www"` with `path = "./www"`

Comment: great！thank you very much @YBS, now I get the idea. Problem solved. How can I mark this post as solved?

Comment: You can accept the answer as it might help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it can run locally with

`path = "/Users/u/myapp/www"`,

it is best to specify relative path while running on shiny server as

`path = "./www"`

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't the answer in this case, but another potential problem if anyone comes searching for the same errors as me, i.e.

- "Warning: Error in : `path` does not exist"
- "shiny app works locally but not on shinyapps.io"

In my case the problem was that I was specifying a filepath this way:

`path <- ".\\DATA\\myData.xlsx"`

which worked locally. The fix was to replace the backslashes:

`path <- "./DATA/myData.xlsx"`