# Shiny app with mp4 movie runs locally, but not on shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny, png, mp4, shinyapps

Consider the following minimal reprex:

```
library(shiny)
library(stringr)
library(av)

ui <- fluidPage(
   
   sidebarPanel(

      actionButton('movie_run', "Let's Go!")
      
   ), 
   
   mainPanel(uiOutput("movie"))
   
)


server <- function (input, output) {
   
   observeEvent(input$movie_run, {
      
      output$movie <- NULL
      
      for (i in 1:48) {
         
         plot.mat <- matrix(data = rnorm(n = 100), nrow = 10, ncol = 10)
         
         png(filename = file.path("www", paste0(str_pad(
             string = i, width = 3, side = "left", pad = "0"), ".png")))
         
         print("PNG file successfully created!")
         
         par(mar = rep(0,4))
         
         print("Margins successfully set!")
         
         image(plot.mat)
         
         print("Image successfully plotted!")
         
         dev.off()
         
         print("Plotting Device successfully closed!")
         
      }
      
      png.files <- file.path("www", list.files(path = "www", pattern = "\\.png$"))
      
      av_encode_video(input = png.files, 
                      output = file.path("www", "movie.mp4"), 
                      framerate = 24)
      
      unlink(x = png.files)
      
      output$movie <- renderUI({
         
         tags$video(
            width="auto", height="auto", controls="", autoplay = "", loop = "", 
            tags$source(src=paste0("movie.mp4"), type="video/mp4")
         )
         
      })
      
   })
   
}
```

(The app requires to have a folder called "www" in the app folder)

The app runs fine on my local machine (specs see below), but on [shinyapps.io](https://shinyapps.io) I get in the logs:

```
[1] "PNG file successfully created!"
[1] "Margins successfully set!"
Warning: Error in plot.new: could not open file 'www/001.png'
15: <Anonymous>
13: fn
8: retry
7: connect$retryingStartServer
6: eval
5: eval
4: eval
3: eval
2: eval.parent
1: local
```

And the application greys out and shows a "Disconnected from the Server. Reload" message.

I have consulted [this FAQ](https://support.posit.co/hc/en-us/articles/229848967-Why-does-my-app-work-locally-but-not-on-shinyapps-io-#:%7E:text=Your%20application%20may%20be%20dependent,bundle%20includes%20all%20necessary%20files.) and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34774826/9808337), which suggests to use `file.path` for platform-independent file paths and `graphics.off` to close plotting devices, to no avail. [This related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68758779/9808337) was solved by using relative file paths, which I did anyway.

Curiously enough, the app sometimes, but rarely works.

I'm wondering whether my storage space on shinyapps.io could be the problem (other apps running), but according to the [shinyapps.io documentation](https://docs.posit.co/shinyapps.io/Storage.html), this should not be the case (ephemeral storage, data deleted after a session is closed).

Local `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 4.3.0 Patched (2023-05-02 r84382)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Ventura 13.0.1

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib 
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib;  LAPACK version 3.11.0

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/C/en_US.UTF-8

time zone: Europe/Zurich
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] rsconnect_1.0.1 av_0.8.3        stringr_1.5.0   shiny_1.7.4    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] crayon_1.5.2     vctrs_0.6.2      cli_3.6.1        rlang_1.1.1      stringi_1.7.12   renv_1.0.0       promises_1.2.0.1
 [8] jsonlite_1.8.4   xtable_1.8-4     glue_1.6.2       openssl_2.0.6    askpass_1.1      htmltools_0.5.5  httpuv_1.6.9    
[15] sass_0.4.6       jquerylib_0.1.4  ellipsis_0.3.2   fastmap_1.1.1    lifecycle_1.0.3  memoise_2.0.1    compiler_4.3.0  
[22] Rcpp_1.0.11      rstudioapi_0.14  later_1.3.1      digest_0.6.31    R6_2.5.1         curl_5.0.2       magrittr_2.0.3  
[29] bslib_0.4.2      tools_4.3.0      withr_2.5.0      mime_0.12        cachem_1.0.8
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How big is the image file that's created when you run this locally? I suggest you download Shiny Server and try this code on your own server locally. If it works it's probably something to do with file permissions or storage space on shinyapps.io.

Comment: One of the 48 png files is about 7KB, the .mp4 is about 70KB. So really small.
Shiny server seems to be available just for Linux machines, which I don't have (I'm working on a Mac). Maybe somebody else can try to reproduce?

Comment: Side note: don't use `file.path("www", list.files(path = "www", pattern = "\\.png$"))`, instead just add `full_names=TRUE`, as in `list.files(path = "www", pattern = "\\.png$", full_names = TRUE)`.

Comment: The warning says you tried to make a file name with a slash. Not a good idea. Also avoid other characters that might be directory separators or url such as "\" or ";".

Comment: Are you certain that the `www/` directory exists? It might be useful to add `dir.create("www", showWarnings=FALSE)` before your `for` loop; if it doesn't exist it will fix a problem, if it already exists then nothing changes.

Comment: IRTFM: That slash is not part of the filename, but of the path. I need relative paths within the app.

Comment: r2evans, dir.create: Thank you, that did the trick! It seems ```rsconnect::deployApp``` does not copy empty directories from the local app to the server. When I put a .txt file into www locally and deploy then, it works. Feel free to post this as an answer. And sorry for the late reply, I wanted to test thoroughly first.